# How to pass instance of a object from one class to another in C#?

Tags: c#, oop

Suppose I have created a Winforms UI Class instance in one class,
Now I want to access that instance of UI class to Hide that from some another class's method.

I'm currently creating a static property of UI class and storing the instance in that property from first class and accessing that static property from another class to get the same instance. But this seems very ineffective as for every Data pass I need to create different properties.

Is there any other better way I can pass instance of a class created in one class to another class in C# directly?

Comment: You'd probably want to avoid that in general. But it's hard to tell without more details. You might want to turn around the flow ("Tell, don't ask"): If you need something to be displayed on that UI, you should pass the data, not the UI component.

Comment: @Fildor
I need instance of that object to ask that " UI_instance.Hide( ); "
How would you suggest I tell the same from other class..execution time?

Comment: In that case, I'd say that's actually a concern of the parent. So, you would do/have something like a ViewModel for the parent, where you set a switch _or_ have a method `HideXY()` or something like that. Maybe it could be triggered by a callback or event ... there really are many possibilities, but exposing the component to the "outside" has some smell to it.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if i get your question correctly by as far as i do i would go with static constructor in the class. Look up this example:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/static-constructor-in-C-Sharp-and-their-usages/

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).